# Options to deal with 43" monitor with MBP

Tags: display

I bought a 43" monitor to replace two other monitors.  I am regretting it because it is difficult to get the scale correct on applications.  The applications are just bigger.  Using Chrome as an example I have to keep clicking the zoom down feature as it keeps resetting to 100%.  Plus, some website do not respond well to a zoom 50%, let alone 25%.

My Colleague has a 43" monitor connected to windows 10 and has it configured to act like four separate monitors.  He said the software he is using came from Dell.

How can I do a similar thing with Mac?

I like this idea because then I would not need to move the mouse so far to get to the menu across the top of the monitor.

[EDIT] After accepting the answer I had to go thru some experimentation to get VMWare Fusion to display properly.  This seemed to be the best setting for fusion:

[image: VMWare Fusion Display Setup Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your goal is to be able to see as much as possible, even if that makes it smaller. In contrast, some people buy larger monitors so that everything appears larger, perhaps to compensate for poor eyesight.

Luckily macOS can accomodate for both preferences. In the System Preferences, under Displays, you can enable **Scaled** mode and choose **More Space** so that everything appears smaller, and you can see more things on screen at once.

[image]